# Send packet to BLE HID Device

Tags: python, linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus

I built a bluetooth keyboard macro, and connected it normally to my linux machine, however I need to send custom packets from Central to the device (in python), as information of which window is currently focused among other things. Is there a way to do this? A two-way communication between device and machine, without needing a dedicated BLE HID client?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can add your custom BLE service, separate to HID. Then use the standard bluez d-bus API to communicate with it.